# AngularJs: Cannot call function linked by a directive in child module?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My program failed to call a function linked by my angulrJS directive. The below are my codes:

"index.html"

```
 <script src="parent.js"></script>
 <script src="child.js"></script>
```

"parent.html"

```
  <div ng-include="'child.html'"></div>
```

"parent.js"

```
angular.module('parent-app', [
  'child-app'
])
 .config(function ($stateProvider) {
  $stateProvider
 .state('parent', {
    url: '/',
    templateUrl: 'parent.html',
    controller: 'parentCtrl'
  })
 ;
})
.controller('parentCtrl',function ($scope) {
 });
```

"child.html"

```
<div ng-controller="childCtrl">
   <a myDirective > Hello World </a>
<div>
```

"child.js" (this is a sub-module)

```
angular.module('child-app', [])
 .controller('childCtrl', function ($scope) {
})

 .directive('myDirective', function() {
 return {
   restrict : 'A',
   link : function($scope, $element) {
     $element.hover(function(){
        alert('get called');

      },
       function(){
      });

   }
 };
 });
```

When I move the mouse to "Hello World", the function linked by "myDirective" is not get called.
Can anyone give me some suggestion?

Thanks,

Comment: any errors? Is jQuery included in page before angular.js since jQlite doesn't have `hover()`?

Comment: @Donal if OP can see the text , must be loading templates no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is in how you declare your directive.

When you name directive with camelCase it will refer to hyphenated attribute.

Change

```
<a myDirective > Hello World </a>
```

To

```
<a my-directive > Hello World </a>
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/0w9gAfm3DNOWY3ngDtUt?p=preview)**</kbd>